Time to be scared
Which person should replace the question mark?



The answer is this guy:

 
SEAN CUNNINGHAM

Why

 If we look at the rebus and  identify the missing letters in the grids next to each of the people’s photos we get DMY respectively and this stands for DAY MONTH and YEAR.

Then

 if we identify the people we can find that they are FILM DIRECTORS:
Rob Marshall
Lucky McKee
Mohideen Abdul Khadar, otherwise known as Rajkiran.

And so

 We are looking to fill the DD/M/YYYY format and how do we do so? Well if by looking at each of their movies one can find
 NINE, MAY and 1980 respectively does the job quite nicely.

Then

 If we look for the date of  9/5/1980 and using the title as a guide to find a movie related to horror, one will find that on this day, the famous horror movie Friday the 13th premiered.

And so

 Since we are looking a missing director, the answer is the director of this movie which is SEAN CUNNINGHAM.


Nice job, this is ofc it!
